# Compose - How to have a continues ripple effect while button is pressed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to have a button and show a continues ripple effect while the button is pressed and only stops when the user releases the button.

Something like this GIF

[image]

I'm already using `MutableInteractionSource` to detect pressed state

```
val interactionSource = remember {
    MutableInteractionSource()
}
val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
```